# Why sort document by id is slower with $match than not in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

So, I tried to query

```
db.collection('collection_name').aggregate([
    {
        $match: { owner_id: '5be9b2f03ef77262c2bd49e6' }
    },
    {
        $sort: { _id: -1 }
    }])
```

the query above takes up 20s

but If I tried to query

```
db.collection('collection_name').aggregate([{$sort : {_id : -1}}])
```

it's only take 0.7s

Why does it the one without $match is actually faster than without match ?

**update :** 
when I try this query

```
db.getCollection('callbackvirtualaccounts').aggregate([
    {
        $match: { owner_id: '5860457640b4fe652bd9c3eb' }
    },
    {
        $sort: { created: -1 }
    }
])
```

it's only takes 0.781s

Why sort by _id is slower than by created field ?

note : I'm using mongodb v3.0.0

Comment: because the `$match` will scan all collection' documents to filter them, then apply `$sort` on the filtered documents.

Comment: `_id` is an indexed field and the field inside `$match` i.e. `owner_id` might not have indexed.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection('collection_name').aggregate([
{
    $match: { owner_id: '5be9b2f03ef77262c2bd49e6' }
},
{
    $sort: { _id: -1 }
}])
```

This collection probably won't be having and index on owner_id; Try using below mentioned index creation query and rerun your previous code.

```
db.collection('collection_name').createIndexes({ owner_id:1}) //Simple Index
 or 
db.collection('collection_name').createIndexes({ owner_id:1,_id:-1}) //Compound Index
```

**Note:: If you don't know how to compound index yet, you can create simple indexes individually on all keys which are used either in match or sort and that should be making query efficient as well.

Comment: But why when I tried to sorted by created which is unindexed field is so much faster ?

Answer (score 0):

The query speed depends upon a lot of factors. The size of collection, size of the document, indexes defined on the collection (and used in the queries and properly), the hardware components (like CPU, RAM, network) and other processes running at the time the query is running.

You have to tell what indexes are defined on the collection being discussed for further analysis. The command will retrieve them: `db.collection.getIndexes()`

Note the unique index on the `_id` field is created by default, and cannot be modified or deleted.

(i)

> But If I tried to query: `db.collection.aggregate( [ { $sort : { _id : -1 } } ] )` it's 
>   only take 0.7s.

The query is faster because there is an index on the `_id` field and it is used in sort process. Aggregation queries use indexes with sort stage and when this sort happens early in the pipeline. You can verify if the index is used or not by generating a query plan (use `explain` with `executionStats` mode). There will be an index scan (IXSCAN) in the generated query plan.

(ii)

> ```
> db.collection.aggregate([
>     {
>         $match: { owner_id: '5be9b2f03ef77262c2bd49e6' }
>     },
>     {
>         $sort: { _id: -1 }
>     }
> ])
> ```
>
> The query above takes up 20s.
>
> When I try this query it's only takes 0.781s.
>
> ```
> db.collection.aggregate([
>     {
>         $match: { owner_id: '5860457640b4fe652bd9c3eb' }
>     },
>     {
>         $sort: { created: -1 }
>     }
> ])
> ```
>
> Why sort by _id is slower than by created field ?

Cannot come to any conclusions with the available information. *In general*, the `$match` and `$sort` stages present early in the aggregation query can use any indexes created on the fields used in the operations.

Generating a *query plan* will reveal what the issues are.

Please run the `explain` with `executionStats` mode and post the query plan details for all queries in question. There is documentation for Mongodb v3.0.0 version on generation query plans using *explain*: [db.collection.explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html)